# ASP.NET Core This localhost page can’t be found

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-mvc

Does anyone encountered this kind of problem? I think it has something to do with the IIS or so... I am using IIS 10 also using VS2017 and ASP.NET Core. When I launch the application I saw this error:

> This localhost page can’t be found
>
> No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:44306/

I tried changing the port. But nothing works.
I tried other application it works but only this project having this kind of error and I don't know why.

Any Idea how to fix this?

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: Did you set default startup page? Are you sure you have a page on that project. Did you enable directory browsing(IIS)?  Don't be agitated just fix your problem one by one till you got the clear solution.

Comment: did you delete the Home View / controller

Comment: How can I set fefault startup page? I already set the startup project on my website. also i use this route: `app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();`

Comment: is your project working in local PC?

Comment: I am working on my local PC, in fact this is the only project is having this kind of issue other do work.

Comment: then compare it to your other project..

Comment: Sorry my bad! I commented my Index page thats why this isn't working. Right now it is totally fine..

Comment: Thanks for the help @reds

Comment: Good to hear that.. good luck

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I solved this problem when I realized I had accidentially removed the default route in the StartUp class' Configure method:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: This help me to solve my problem when logging in and use an `[Authorize]` attribute to my index page without using an Entity Framework. That problem takes 2 weeks. I am frustrated. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 27):

This is similar to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49910056/283787), but shows how to define routes in .Net Core version 3.0

I was having a similar problem when trying to hit my API endpoint https://localhost:44380/api/Restaurants

In order to map my routes for an API controller class that inherited from the `ControllerBase` class, I needed to add the line `endpoints.MapControllers` to `Configure` method of `Startup.cs` class, as follows:

```
        //Pre .NET core 3.0 way of doing things
        //app.UseMvc(routes => {<some routing stuff here>});

        //.NET core 3.0 way
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages(); //Routes for pages
            endpoints.MapControllers(); //Routes for my API controllers
        });
```

Answer (score 11):

If the answer above doesn't work or you're coming from the .NET Web API tutorial, this might help. So for me, I removed the `launchUrl` property from `launchSettings.json` because I wanted to use a static page (per the instructions of the tutorial I'm following) and forgot to add 2 lines in my haste. I finally went back and looked over it and this solved my issue.

Open the `Startup.cs` file and inside `public void Configure...` add the following above the `app.UseMvc();` line:

`app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();`

Comment: if using .net core 2.1 
your solution is right
but you need to add this line 
            services.AddMvc();

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem but the mistake was a silly one hence the solution very easy!
there was a typo in my route 
I added a space by mistake after Controller Name
I know its not very Technical Answer but it won`t harm to double check

was:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("Default", "{controller= Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Corrected to:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("Default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); 
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem, it turned out I unintentionately changed my Index() method of HomeController to property through refactoring

```
public ViewResult Index() => View()
```

became

```
public ViewResult Index => View();
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I modify the `index` name to `HomePage`, and I resolve it by check several places:

(You can search `index` in your entire solution to check)

1. In `Views/_Layout.cshtml`

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="HomePage">xxx</a>
```

2. In `Startup.cs`

```cs
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=HomePage}/{id?}");
});
```

3. In `Controllers/HomeController.cs`

```cs
public IActionResult HomePage()
{
    return View();
}
```

After I edit the three places, it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure project, lauchsettings.json ports are set correctly.

Comment: actually its my bad, I commented my index page that is why they can't find the index page and it shows the error. right now its been fixed.

Comment: how did u solve it

Answer (score 0):

if this is happening you are missing wwwroot folder.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because I had copied a .net core 1 Razor Page into my .net core 2.2 project. I added a @page declaration to the Razor Page and everything worked. Just adding this here because this is the first Google result for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Be sure to check and try these items:**

1. Change port number in project properties.
2. Reset IIS in cmd using "iisreset" command.
3. Checked the StartUp.cs to ensure

   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "default",
   pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
   });
4. Restarted VS and laptop but to no avail too.
5. Checked launchSetting.json but everything is correct.

Comment: This answer is practically a copy and paste from [this question](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1279470/This-localhost-page-cant-be-found-No-webpage-was-f). If you are going to use answers from other places on the web, make sure the copyright/site allows it and add a link attribute/reference to where you got the information.

Answer (score 0):

In your project, go to properties -> launchSettings.json (double click)

in iisSettings -> iisExpress -> applicationUrl (change the port number for your localhost)

and try again, issue should be solved successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just switching to another localhost's port that ISS provided while launching. On the first one there was an error "page not found" but second one worked as it supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

This happens every time I add a razor page to my project.
The solution is to, in Visual Studio, click on the cshtml file and then set "Build Action" from "None" to "Content". Fixes the issue every time (for me).