# One controller gives "This localhost page can’t be found"

Tags: c#, error-handling, routes, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .Net Core 2 Api. A few controllers (UserController, CarController). If I start the Api I can browser to the UserController and it shows me a list of users, perfect!
When I browse to the CarController it gives me an error:

> This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web
>   address: http://localhost:57880/Car Search Google for localhost
>   57880 Car HTTP ERROR 404

Each controller has a route-name. So I changed the route-name of the CarController to "DummyTest". I restarted the API, browse to DummyTest and it works! User still works as normal.
Why?... I can't seem to figure out why "Car" gives a 404 and the same controller with a different route (DummyTest) works.

I found this on StackOverflow: [ASP.NET Core This localhost page can’t be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468715/asp-net-core-this-localhost-page-can-t-be-found), but this isn't a fix for me.

**EDIT**

Here is the code of the controller that gives the 404:

```
[Route("Car")]
public class CarController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICarService _carService;

    public CarController(ICarService carService)
    {
        _carService= carService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<Car> Get()
    {
        return _carService.GetCars().ToList();
    }
}
```

Here is the code of the controller that does work:

```
[Route("User")]
public class UserController : Controller
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public List<User> Get()
    {
        return _userService.GetUsers().ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Add code sample of your controller and routing. Also do you using naming convention?

Comment: @J.Doe See my edit

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to debug your problem without seeing your code, but I can offer some speculation.

If you're using attribute-based routing, it could be that you're specifying a route template instead of a route name.

```
[Route("CarController")]
public class CarController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

This will give you a 404 if you navigate to **http://localhost:xxxxx/Car** due to the naming convention for controllers.

Try this route template instead:

```
[Route("Car")]
public class CarController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edit. I added the code, which shows that I use the correct naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to me because I had copied a .net core 1 Razor Page into my .net core 2.2 project. I added a @page declaration to the Razor Page and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the "launchUrl": "swagger" for the "IIS Express" profile in the launchSettings.json files. Somehow it was removed.