# Service Fabric ASP.Net core Stateful reliable service giving This localhost page can’t be found error

Tags: azure, localhost, azure-service-fabric, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to azure service fabric, I am trying to run it on Service Fabric, with VS2017.

I created a service fabric application and added ASP.Net core state full reliable service.
When i run it (with out any changes to core application), I am getting error

**This localhost page can’t be found (HTTP Error 410)**

I am not sure what is missing, can someone please help?

I tried switching between Kestrel and Web Listeners
Following [ASP.NET Core This localhost page can’t be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468715/asp-net-core-this-localhost-page-can-t-be-found)

**In asp.net core startup.cs I added**

```
app.UseMvc(routes => {
                routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

**I did not change anything in lauchsettings.json**

**In CreateServiceReplicaListeners I have**  (I get same error with default Kestrel listner also) :

```
return new ServiceReplicaListener[]
{
    new ServiceReplicaListener(serviceContext =>
        new HttpSysCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint",  (url, listener) =>
        {
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting web server {url}");

            return new WebHostBuilder()
                        .UseHttpSys()
                        .ConfigureServices(
                            services => services
                                .AddSingleton<StatefulServiceContext>(serviceContext)
                                .AddSingleton<IReliableStateManager>(this.StateManager))
                        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                        .UseStartup<Startup>()
                        .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl)
                        .UseUrls(url)
                        .Build();
        }))
}; 

**In serviceManifest.xml**
<Resources>
    <Endpoints>
      <Endpoint Port="8052" Protocol="http" Name="ServiceEndpoint"  Type="Input"/>
    </Endpoints>
</Resources>
```

http://localhost:8052/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None` instead of `ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.UseUniqueServiceUrl`.

The latter is used with dynamic port assignments.

> With dynamic port assignment, this setting prevents the mistaken
>   identity issue described earlier.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#service-fabric-integration-middleware).

Note: It's not recommended to use HttpSys in [stateful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-aspnetcore#httpsys-in-a-stateful-service) services.

> HttpSysCommunicationListener isn't currently designed for use in
>   stateful services due to complications with the underlying HTTP.sys
>   port sharing feature. For more information, see the following section
>   on dynamic port allocation with HTTP.sys. For stateful services,
>   Kestrel is the suggested web server.