# My razor pages are not working all of the generate the same error : Localhost page cant be found

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, razor

[This is my startup.cs file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrXjN.png)

Does anyone know whats going wrong [This is my index.cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSQlI.png)

Alright so my code will be below its very basic startup.cs file and a index.cshtml file  with some basic code just for testing

```
      public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }


        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
         {
          endpoints.MapRazorPages();
         });


    }
}}
```

```
@page

@DateTime.Now
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Sorry about that i'm new have added it in now as code

Comment: Any relevance? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468715/asp-net-core-this-localhost-page-can-t-be-found#49910056

Comment: pls show the code behind the page

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new project and check whether you have the same problem.

And did you apply something to your service side? You can share it.

Or you can try these code first:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;
        });
```

Configure:

```
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```