# ASP.NET Core "This localhost page cannot be found"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, localhost

I'm trying to set up ASP.NET Core 3.1 app on Docker by first running a localhost but the page cannot be found. Posted below are my Startup.cs and launchSettings.json files. When I do `dotnet run`, the web server builds and is now listening on: `https://localhost:7165` and `http://localhost:5233`.

`Program.cs`

```
/**
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
**/

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Commander {
    public class Program{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

`Startup.cs`

```
namespace Commander{
    public class Startup{
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration){
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        //This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){   //Adding DB context
            services.AddDbContext<CommanderContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer
                (Configuration.GetConnectionString("CommanderConnection")));
            
            services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(s => {
                s.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            });

            services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            
            services.AddScoped<ICommanderRepo, SqlCommanderRepo>(); //Dependency injection
        }

        //This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){
            if(env.IsDevelopment()){
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`launchSettings.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:16100",
      "sslPort": 44329
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Commander": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7165;http://localhost:5233",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings":
  {
    "CommanderConnection": "Server=LILCLARISSA\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CommanderDB;User ID=CommanderAPI;Password=pass;Encrypt=false;TrustServerCertificate=true;" 
  }
}
```

`appsettings.Development.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried https://localhost:7165/weatherforecast and http://localhost:5233/weatherforecast but neither seem to work. I also tried adding `endpoints.AddRazorPages();` in the `Configure` method and other services in `ConfigureServices` but nothing seems to be working. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you changed anything in your configuration file? It's difficult to find the reason just based on the code you provided, Maybe you can refer to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468715/asp-net-core-this-localhost-page-can-t-be-found).

Comment: I haven't changed anything except adding ConnectionStrings to the appsettings.json file. I've also been trying the solutions in the link you sent, but none seem to be working.

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild your project or restart your visual studio? You can create a new project and try again. Maybe the issue is caused by visual studio instead of your project.

Answer (score 0):

as I remember, you should map the local port to docker, `7165` and `5233` only your dotnet app localhost port, but you need to access through docker, so you should map these ports to docker and you can access them from outside.

```
docker run -p <DOCKER_PORT_NUMBER>:<APPLICATION_PORT_NUMBER> docker/getting-started
```